# Powershell copy file/folder based on keyword

Tags: powershell, copy

I want to copy folder which match with the keyword. however i want powershell read the keyword from starting point. i added my script below

if any folder name contain test at the start, script will copy the folder. but it's coping all folder even if "Test" keyword is available in the middle name. like if there is two folder

"This.is.a.Test.Folder"
"Test.this.is.a.Folder"

I want powershell copy only "Test.this.is.a.Folder"

any help please

````
$dest = "D:\2";
$include= @("*Test*")
Get-ChildItem $source -recurse -Force -Verbose -include $include | copy-Item -Destination {Join-Path $dest $_.FullName.Substring($source.length)}```
````

Comment: Remove the first *asterisk* (`*`) from `"Test"*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wildcard is meant to capture anything that contains the word **Test** in this case.

- If you want to specifically start with the word *Test* followed by anything: `Test*`
- Contrary, anything that ends with the word *Test* would be: `*Test`

```
$include = @( "Test*" )
Get-ChildItem $source -Include $include -Recurse -Force -Verbose |
Copy-Item -Destination {
   Join-Path $dest -ChildPath $_.FullName.Substring($source.length)
}
```

---

Note, that you can use `-File` to filter only files and `-Directory` to filter only folders.

Comment: i don't know but i tried that before make the post but did not work, but this time worked. thank you for the reply.

Comment: @firekid2018 Happy to help :) I would personally use `Split-Path $_.FullName -Leaf` instead of `$_.FullName.Substring($source.length)`